# @Html.Action post state model not doesn't affect partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

in BooksController

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult CommentForm(int bookid)
    {
        var model = new CommentSurrogate();
        model.BookID = bookid;
        model.Date = DateTime.Now;
        return PartialView("_CommentForm", model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult CommentForm(CommentSurrogate model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Session["commentSec"] as string == model.SecurityCode)
            {
                model.Date = DateTime.Now;
                CommentRepository repo = new CommentRepository();
                repo.Save(model);
                ViewBag.CommentMessage = "Yorumunuz başarıyla kaydedilmiştir. Editörlerimiz tarafından incelenip onaylandıktan sonra yayınlanacaktır.";
                return PartialView("_CommentForm", new CommentSurrogate {Date = DateTime.Now, BookID= model.BookID });
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("SecurityCode","Güvenlik kodunu yanlış girdiniz.");
        }
        return PartialView("_CommentForm", model);
    }
```

in BookDetailView

```
@Html.Action("CommentForm", "Books", new { bookid = Model.ID })
```

when i write comment and post using comment form. calling  CommentForm action with [HttpPost] attribute. And im saving model, no problem at this time.

```
return PartialView("_CommentForm", new CommentSurrogate {Date = DateTime.Now, BookID= model.BookID });
```

but _CommentForm seems not to have retrived new CommentSurrogate model which has passed by the code above. After post action comment form still has the data of the current posted data.

_CommentForm.cshtml

```
@model Yayinevi.Data.Surrogates.CommentSurrogate
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="respond" class="clearfix">

    <div class="title-block" style="margin: 0 0 30px 0;">
        <h3>Kitap Hakkında Yorum Yazın</h3>
    </div>
    @if (@ViewBag.CommentMessage != null)
    {
        <div class="msg success"><p>@ViewBag.CommentMessage</p></div>
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookID)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="field-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text_input" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:15px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="field-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text_input" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:15px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="field-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text_input", cols = "60", rows = "9" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:15px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="field-row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityCode)
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="@(Url.Action("Captcha", "Layout", new { SessionName="commentSec"}))" /> <br />@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text_input" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:15px;" })
    </div>
    <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Gönder" id="submit" name="submit">
</div>
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for _CommentForm view? After the POST you're going to get the CommentForm view populated by the model you pass into the method plus the new date thats set.

Comment: I have posted _CommentForm.cshtml file content. CommentSurrogate.Date = new DateTime.Now doesn't matter.

Comment: One more question, how do you know it doesn't get the new model? Do you get an error? Is the data wrong if so which bit etc?

Comment: response html contain post values in _CommentForm section. I want clear the form after post.